# How to create non-singular symmetric matrix from random numbers in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I want to create a non-singular symmetric matrix using random real numbers.

for example, I want to create a `3*3` non-singular symmetric matrix using randomly generated real numbers

```
number_list= [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

I tried the following but still, I am getting singular matrix sometimes.

```
  upper = tfp.math.fill_triangular(number_list, upper=True)
  
  symm= 0.5 * (upper + tf.transpose(upper, perm=[0,2,1]))
 
  final =tf.matmul(symm, tf.transpose(symm, perm=[0,2,1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`tfp.bijectors.FillScaleTriL()(number_list)` will make a psd cholesky factor for you from a triangular sized list of numbers.
`tfb.CholeskyOuterProduct()` will make a covariance matrix.
The combination could be written `bij = tfb.CholeskyOuterProduct()(tfb.FillScaleTriL()); bij(number_list)`.